# How to save soap play to file in apache camel?

Tags: apache-camel

Tried to save `soap` request (jaxb payload) to file as `xml` payload in apache camel, via below code, but it failed.

Anyone know how to do it?

Any hints will be more than welcome!

Code:

```
public class CamelRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    private static final String SOAP_ENDPOINT_URI = "cxf://http://localhost:{{soapEndpointPort}}/soap" +
        "?serviceClass=org.yw.springbootcamelesb.soap.CreateFileService";

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from(SOAP_ENDPOINT_URI).process(new CreateFileProcessor()).to("file:target/reports");;
    }
}
```

exception I got is like below

> pringbootcamelesb.soap.FileCreationStatus on:
>   Message[ID-YandeMBP-1536989276152-2-2]. Caused by: No type converter
>   available to convert from type:
>   org.yw.springbootcamelesb.soap.FileCreationStatus to the required
>   type: java.io.InputStream with value
>   org.yw.springbootcamelesb.soap.FileCreationStatus@75ec37c5.
>   Exchange[ID-YandeMBP-1536989276152-2-1]. Caused by:
>   [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type
>   converter available to convert from type:
>   org.yw.springbootcamelesb.soap.FileCreationStatus to the required
>   type: java.io.InputStream with value
>   org.yw.springbootcamelesb.soap.FileCreationStatus@75ec37c5]
>         at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:117)
>   ~[camel-core-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
>         at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:333)
>   ~[camel-core-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
>         ... 40 common frames omitted

Answer (score 0):

it works with below code

```
        JaxbDataFormat xmlDataFormat = new JaxbDataFormat();
    JAXBContext con = JAXBContext.newInstance(FileCreationStatus.class);
    xmlDataFormat.setContext(con);
    from(SOAP_ENDPOINT_URI).process(new CreateFileProcessor())
            .marshal(xmlDataFormat).to("file:target/output").unmarshal(xmlDataFormat);
```